# Executors Schedule in different intervals

Tags: java, scheduler, executors

I try to schedule a Executors with newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor that send a report after 10 days(from the initialized of the system), after 20 days(from the initialized of the system) and every 1st of the month.
I tried to use newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor that runs every day and check if today is after 10 days.. 20 days and etc.
But, I think we have a more elegant way to solve this with some executors.
Do you have any idea how can I improve my code?

The scheduler:

```
   scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> {
        try {
            createReport();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error to create engagement report", e);
        }
    }, 1, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

and on the createReport function - I check the dates.

Thanks!

Comment: Look at some library like `Quartz`  at http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I use ScheduledExecutorService schedule that initializing in the constructor:

```
scheduler.schedule(createTask , nextDayOfTask, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

So, every time I get to the `createTask` - I re-calc when the next report should get out and update the schedule.

```
public Runnable createTask = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do What Ever You Need 
        scheduler.schedule(this, nextDayOfTask, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    }
};
```